# How to make click action to wait before input box is filled with value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to filled the input box and click the button and go to next page. But problem is that sometimes input value is too long and before value is completely inserted in input box, button is clicked. How to solve this problem.

```
await page.keyboard.type('input value'); //input 
await page.click('#btn'); //button to clicked
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
await page.waitFor(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cant add a comment, I really need to know what is before the first line of code but I assume is a focus on your input so will give you a hint.

The problem is in the `keyboard.type` we don't have a promise and the test continue running. So we need to remove `focus` and `keyboard.type`, and use `page.type(selector, text[, options])`:

```
await page.type('#id_input', 'long input value');
```

This issues will be common over time so I also added a slow down in my project of 20 milliseconds; isn't a huge impact.

```
puppeteer.launch({slowMo: 20}).then(async browser => {...}
```

Comment: that works, but it created another error: (node:7939) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
when I goto another page, it stop there.

Comment: Perfect, the problem it's in another place. Its hard to know were without all the code. But check first the waitForNavigation use one o this two lines: `await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });` or `await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' });`. Personal the load works for me.